# Unexpected error while getting the method or property getAuthorizationInfo on object ScriptApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an apps script running behind a Google Form and just in the last couple of weeks, I have been getting an error from my code.

The problem code is:

```
var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
```

And the error is:

> Unexpected error while getting the method or property
> getAuthorizationInfo on object ScriptApp.

The code is now running under the V8 engine.

Comment: I have had somewhat similar problems on V8 I was able to get it running by putting all of my scopes into the manifest file.

Comment: Adding the all my scopes to the manifest file worked perfectly. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: Hello @SB1100, could you report the issue on https://issuetracker.google.com, in the `Public Trackers > G Suite Developers > Apps Script` component? I would do it myself but I could not reproduce it. Thanks!

Comment: @Cooper can you should exactly how to do that instead of just saying "put all scopes into manifest file".
`
scopes: ['all']
`
?

Answer (score 5):

If you tried fixing the v8 engine oauth scoping issue as mentioned in other answers and that still doesn't work, be sure to **pass in valid arguments (especially of the right type)** to the method mentioned in the error.

I got an "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp" error because my trigger handler took some default parameters (including sheet ID) that I overrode for testing, and I hadn't realized that Apps Script actually passes in some parameters (the event object). I ended up calling "SpreadsheetApp.openById" on the event object instead of ID string. And, the error made it sound like it was failing before the argument even got passed in, so it was a pain to track down. Anyway, fwiw, the arguments do matter, and it's not necessarily a scoping issue.

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked for an example of how to copy the scopes into the manifest file:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who could face this issue:

As @Cooper mentioned, writing the scopes in the manifest file (`View > Show Manifest file`) provides a workaround for the issue.

Comment: Go to file -> project properties -> scopes to see the current permissions and paste them in. Note that Apps Script docs seem to be pretty good about listing all the scopes required for each authorized function.